# Cant connect to other networks

Tags: wireless, networking

I have a HP laptop running Ubuntu. I was able to connect to my home wireless network without any problems.

When I tried using it at work, I couldn't connect. I can click on the network desired, but absolutely nothing else happens when I click on `Connect` or on `Settings`

Additionally, the WiFi icon is never shown on the start bar